# JSON viewer for browsing APIs

Tags: json, browser, visualization, visualizer

Does anyone have any recommendations for applications or browser plugins that make browsing and visualizing JSON APIs easy. Please support your answer with a reference or link to the application you recommend.

Comment: I'm looking for the quickest way to get from a URL such as http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23StackOverflow to a nicely formatted view of the data

Comment: Some ideas: http://rajakannappan.blogspot.com/2014/07/json-desktop-editors.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This one looks quite good, it's a firefox plugin called JSONView
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869

Also ported to a chrome extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

**Addition**
Postman is an awesome stand-alone program for working with APIs
https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: JSONView's biggest flaw is it only handles application/json. We need support for application/*+json but according to https://github.com/bhollis/jsonview/issues/7 FireFox might not support it.

Answer (score 9):

Johns tool is nice. Anoter nice online tool is http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 7):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking.

- If you're looking for a JSON viewer to examine complex JSON strings, take a look at **[JSON Visualizer](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm)**.
- If you're looking for a way to browse an API, consult that API's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness there is also this [JSON Viewer](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507040130/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=jsonviewer)
I have only tried the stand-alone, and it seems to do the basics ok. However the firefox plugin had less friction for what I was doing.

**From the documentation:**
The JSON View package is a set of 3 viewers available in the following flavors:

1. A standalone viewer - JsonView.exe
2. A plugin for Fiddler 2 (http://www.fiddler2.com/) - FiddlerJsonViewer.dll
3. A visualizer for Viusal Studio 2005  - JsonVisualizer.dll

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple option.
http://jsonviewer.jaycodesign.co.nz/

Just copy the JSON in and see it visualized to the right.

Comment: good to know, but too many clicks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the list here is pretty comprehensive, I'll just add [Jabulr](http://jabulr.com), an online tool that attempts to show JSON in a tabular format. And, yes, it accepts a URL pointing to your JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug in Firefox does the job when you have a url which returns json (Firebug is a must have for any web developer, if you don't have it installed already, you can get it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)): with Firebug open and active navigate to your url in Firefox, in Firebug go to the Net tab, then click + sign next to your url in the grid, there should be a JSON tab available which you can use to explore your object in a tree view.

Comment: I have firebug, don't know what I'd do without it. Mine does not have the json tab. it's v1.5.3

Comment: +1, Note: The tab does not show if the primary download is json. It works for secondary json resources. So for me JSONView does a better job for what I was looking for... but the net > json tab fills a separate role. thanks.