# Which programs can I use to visualize a JSON File?

Tags: json

I need a program to visualize a json response from a URL or a json file, which organizes the data so it's more human readable. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON viewer for browsing APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368229/json-viewer-for-browsing-apis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for an interactive online app, http://jsbeautifier.org/ works great and there are many suggestions for integrating the functionality into other environments.

You can either execute the core of jsbeautifier (beautify-cl.js) in a hosted js runtime or attempt to re-engineer it in the language of your choice.

If you need to reformat JSON at runtime in .net, I can suggest [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 19):

Great online tools:

- ## [json.parser.online.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr) (Online JSON Parser)

  Excellent for **detecting invalid json**, and shows both *json-parse* and *eval* methods.
- ### [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) (JSONLint - The JSON Validator)

  [Open-source](https://github.com/circlecell/jsonlint.com), has excellent validation of **detecting invalid json**, and beautifies JSON.
- [web.archive.org/.../chris.photobooks.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20200326113913/chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm) (JSON Visualization)

  Shows json as html tables and is good for detecting invalid json
- [jsonviewer.stack.hu](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu) (Online JSON Viewer)

  Nice if you want to traverse json as a tree with properties (but bad for invalid json)

Downloadable tool built on .NET:

- [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com)

  Has a stand-alone viewer similar to the online viewer of the same name, but also has **plugins** for **Fiddler 2** and **Visual Studio 2005**

Comment: Yes! http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm is very useful..

Comment: I wrote this one: https://keyserv.solutions/VizBuild/VizBuild.html It is very similar to: http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm

Comment: I found the chris.photobooks.com page through the waybackmachine. Here's a link: `http://web.archive.org/web/20200326113913/chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm`

Comment: http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/ is no more?

Answer (score 10):

To toot my own horn, I've also written a JSON visualizer - it can even fetch a remote url and visualize the JSON it returns.

You can find it at http://json.bloople.net.

Comment: Link is broken: 500

Comment: I wrote one too but yours is a work of art!
Big fan.

Answer (score 10):

- For **mac**: [VisualJSON](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id488709442) on appstore
- For web browser: JSONView as plugin

  - **Firefox**: [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/)
  - **Chrome**: [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)
- For **Terminal**: [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie)

Comment: JSONView only app I found that worked with very large files

Answer (score 5):

I use [JsonLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/), a web based validator and reformatter for JSON. Upon validation, it also reformats the JSON file so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

well to continue the trend here (a couple years later) here is another JSON Visualizer created by myself .. though this one a little bit prettier ;)

[visualizer.json2html.com](http://visualizer.json2html.com)