Any way to visualize JSON Parent/Child object relationships?
I'm fairly new to JSON so apologies if I use any incorrect terminology...
I have a large JSON with lots of parent/child nesting. I'm trying to find a tool that will visual the nesting in a way similar to the example I've included. Anybody know how I could do this? Thanks.
JSON input structure
desired visualization
I played around with Smart JSON Editor and searched the web but found nothing that looks to fit my needs.

I googled "JSON Visualisation" and found JSON Crack and JSON Visio. I assume you have tried them- what features are they missing that you need? Your desired visual would fit what they output, albeit with greater detail. There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826361/which-programs-can-i-use-to-visualize-a-json-file

This question is similar to: Which programs can I use to visualize a JSON File?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
