# can you recommend me a json viewer application?

Tags: json

I need one that will indent the json for ease of reading

1. The famous simple file editors - editplus , notepad++ - they all dont have json doc type.
2. There are a lot of online sites with built in viewer.  I need an offline one.

10x.

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368229/json-viewer-for-browsing-apis) there are answers for both on-line and off-line viewers.

Comment: Also: [Eclipse Json Editor Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/).

Comment: Other ideas: http://rajakannappan.blogspot.com/2014/07/json-desktop-editors.html

Comment: Well not really, http://www.jsonviewers.com/ is bit better and advance than jsonviewer :)

Comment: Firefox has a built-in json viewer. Just open your .json file in Firefox.

Comment: Browser's plugin called jsonview at https://jsonview.com It supports both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have used [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/), it works nicely and is lightweight. However it's really down to your taste or whether you require some specific features. It's probably worth it to take a look at some screenshots of several different ones first.

Comment: It lacks drag-and-drop, which was a deal breaker for me.

Comment: and lacks write support?!

Comment: Decent but quite slow for some operations, even on small files.

Comment: How do you actually use it? I have the chrome extension and all I see is "copy path" and "copy value."

Comment: Only Windows support?

Comment: beware the patent clause in its license.  Looks good otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

The Notepad++ plug in [NPP JSON Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/) worked well for me too, it is a little slow with large amounts of data, but does a good job of formatting long JSON strings and displays a structured tree of the data for click through navigation. It would be nice if the tree was searchable, but unfortunately it is currently not.

Answer (score 9):

I have been using the jsmin pluggin which has both JSON viewer and JSON formatter.  No problem opening 20MB of data.  You can hilight a single json  line and Alt+Ctrl+M to format just one line, or you can format the entire file.

http://www.sunjw.us/jsminnpp

Comment: JSON viewer hanged with my 7mb file =/

Comment: @MarkusKnappenJohansson I found it works better if you first reformat the file, then open the json viewer.

Comment: Lightning fast JSON parser. Much better than NPP JSON Viewer which hanged on a mere 2.5 mb json file, this one parsed it in less than 1 second. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can search in google for notepad++ json plugin... and one of the results => http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/

Comment: strangely enough - it installed but doesnt do anything

Comment: view the readme file. "Select JSON fragment and navigate to plugins/JSON Viewer/show JSON Viewer or press "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J". You have to select some JSON string